# If an object is large enough and slow enough is there a point that we can say we know its position and momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

Let’s say you have a 3000 lb vehicle moving very slow at 1 kilometer per hour. It seems obvious that you could simultaneously determine its position and momentum at any point along the way but does the uncertainty principle still apply even here?

You should be able to calculate this at a future point. If not then why not? If so then at what point do you revert back to uncertainty?

Comment: HOW could you measure it with absolute certainty, is this not where "practical"  uncertainty appears, irrespective of uncertainty principle?

Comment: @StudyStudy why would you need to measure it? You could just calculate where it’s going to be and you already know the momentum. Besides is that all the uncertainty principle is about? When you read about uncertainty principle it gives you the impression that things are s’weird, or not  really there. They make it sound like entangled particles don’t even exist until one of them is measured.

Comment: Suppose you know the momentum of the car to one part in a billion. Try calculating the uncertainty in its position.

Comment: @G.Smith Precision in a single measurement isn't what is covered by the HUP.

Answer (score 3):

"Uncertainty" in the HUP doesn't mean we "don't know" the position or momentum of the particle (or car). What it means is that if we prepare many identical cars in the same way, and then measure their position, we will find that the distribution of measurements have some standard deviation $\Delta x$. If we prepare many identical cars again in the same way, and then measure their momentum, we will find that the distribution of measurements have some standard deviation $\Delta p$. The HUP guarantees that $\Delta x\cdot\Delta p\geq\hbar/2$.

This is not a relation between how well we "know" the position or momentum, for even if we had measuring devices with infinite precision we would still end up with distributions with spreads $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ in our measurements. However what could be an issue is if our measurements themselves have errors that are larger than $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$, because then actually getting a reliable distribution is out of the question.

So, the HUP still applies (if we can treat the car as a particle?). But due to how small $\hbar$ is, it is unlikely that we will be able to actually determine $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ for our system, which once again has nothing to do with how well we can measure the system. Also, treating cars as quantum mechanical probably isn't exactly valid, so this whole analogy might be off anyway, but the reasoning should be sound for better systems. If you want to stretch it to a car analogy, I don't see why not as long as it is used responsibly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point.  It is not a binary shift from uncertainty to certainty.  It's a smooth shift.

For macroscopic objects, measurement errors are typically sufficient to *choose* to ignore the uncertainty.  For such objects, the statistical expectation of the system has so little variance that our ability to measure generates more variability.  That doesn't mean it's gone, it just means we're ignoring it for now.

If a system is stable, that can add additional predictability, by plotting a trajectory which is less dependent on the uncertain unknowns.

Short term predictions are also easier.  We like to think of the path of the planets as being predictable, but actually it's a chaotic N-body problem.  On the order of millions of years, its actually very difficult to predict the future location of a planet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103811/discussion-on-answer-by-cort-ammon-reinstate-monica-if-an-object-is-large-enou).

Answer (score 1):

Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle is **always** valid and forms the basics of modern quantum physics. Let us use the values that you have provided.
$$\Delta x\Delta p\ge \frac h{4\pi }$$
$$\Delta x\Delta p\ge \frac h{4\pi}$$
$$\Delta x\Delta p\ge 5.27285909\times 10^{-35}$$

Let us graciously assume that for whatever reason, you know the correct momentum accurate to $0.000000001\text {kgm/s}$. Then uncertainty in position come to be
$$\Delta x\ge 5.27285909\times 10^{-26}\text m$$
$$\text {or}$$
$$\Delta x\ge 0.0527285909\text { yoctometer}$$
Worrying about a change in position at this scale is a pure waste of time. There doesn't exist any instrument which can measure this type of length. Hence this can be conveniently ignored for our day-to-day calculations.

Comment: Precision in a single measurement isn't what is covered by the HUP

Answer (score -1):

The uncertainty principle only applies to quantum objects such as an electron. A 3000 lb vehicle would not be considered a quantum object.

Comment: So you’re saying there is a point that we can know? That’s what the question was.

Comment: Before I continue, my "answer" is not an answer. It was meant as a comment, but since I need 50 reputation, I was not able to leave that. Anyway, how would you describe "know"? We can not know arbitrarily where it is since it isn't a point particle. A vehicle has dimensions. If you want to know where its edges are to an arbitrary point, you'll be hit with quantum particles at which point the uncertainty principle comes into play.

Comment: I gave you an up vote to help you out because you’re interested in this subject. Is your answer now that there is not a point that we would know? Then why would it  matter if it’s a macro or quantum object?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but I don't get reputation from comments. To address your second part, I cannot give you an answer until you give a definition as what it means "know" an object's position. When we refer to a car's position, we refer to where its center point is, for which we can "know" its position and momentum to an arbitrary point since it isn't a physical object at all, just a point of reference.

Comment: in that case we don’t know where anything is